# Query regarding SQL Workbench access to Redshift cluster endpoint IP Whitelisting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, access-control, aws-security-group

I use a dongle/WiFi to use internet and hence my Public IP is dynamic (changes everyday).

While trying to access SQL Workbench, the IP of the end user has to be added in the default security group under the Network & Security tab of the EC2 dashboard.

Everyday I have to follow this process religiously before starting work on SQL Workbench.

Can anyone guide me to a permanent fix on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permanent fix? **No.**

But a simple way to handle it? **Yes!**

You can run this script on your computer:

```
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name "Redshift-SG" --protocol tcp --port 5439 --cidr $IP/32
```

It will add your current IP address to the Security Group.

After a while, the security group will fill up, so you'll need to empty it out and start again. (You could automate that too!)

Comment: But this doesn't look sophisticated enough. How does big organizations provide/control access to their AWS services then? Neither everyone run these scripts nor are the project admins sitting all day to do the same for users, everyday. Isn't?

Comment: Well, they probably wouldn't make the database accessible from the Internet. Instead, they would require users to login to a Bastion host and use **port forwarding**. This way, the database server can be kept in a private subnet and the bastion connection requires an SSH key to connect. My suggestion is merely offering an easier version of what you are currently doing.